# Can't click on google recaptcha checkbox (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Python 3.9.0, Selenium 3.141.0, Chromedriver 89.0.4389.23

HTML:
[DOM Structure Screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98PA.png)

I've tried several ways, for example:

```
    a = self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "google.com/recaptcha")]'))
    b = self.driver.find_element_by_id("rc-anchor-container").click()
    c = self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Or exactly the same, but with WebDriverWait and different locators (by class name - recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark, recaptcha-checkbox-border) . As a result, I get the error:

```
"message":**"element not interactable"** (about checkbox element, iframe successfully switched)

..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:80: in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:633: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x00000274AC6A5A60>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"element not interactable","message":"element not interactable\\n  (Sessio...\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57C7E+286]
\\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57C4E+238]\\n"}}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from this line:

```
    b = self.driver.find_element_by_id("rc-anchor-container").click()
```

I code a solution in C#, but you'll easily understand and translate it to Python:

```cs
// Load a captcha test page
driver.Url = "https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/";
// Switch to the recaptcha Iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@role='presentation']")));

Thread.Sleep(2000);
// Click on the box
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']")).Click();
```

Comment: Still " Message: element not interactable" :(